# How can I resolve `Error: Could not locate the bindings file.` when using `node-ffi`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ffi, node-ffi

Some details:

- Mac OSX 10.11.6
- Node v6.5.0
- `npm` v3.10.3
- `nvm` v0.29.0

I recently built an `npm` package that interacts with a shared C library using `ffi`. The package works perfectly on its own (built with `babel`). I'm trying to integrate it into a proof-of-concept app and am running into *lots* of problems with `bindings`. I'm using `webpack` to bundle my POC app and that's where I'm running into this issue.

Here's my `webpack.config.js`:

```
/* eslint-disable */
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

var buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'wp-build/');

module.exports = [
  {
    name: 'frontend',
    entry: './src/frontend/index.js',
    output: {
      path: buildPath,
      filename: 'frontend.bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [{
        test: /\.js/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|build)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      }],
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
    ],
    devServer: {
      contentBase: buildPath,
      filename: 'frontend.bundle.js',
      publicPath: '/assets/',
      port: 8000,
      stats: {
        colors: true,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'backend',
    entry: './src/backend/server.js',
    output: {
      path: buildPath,
      filename: 'backend.bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [{
        test: /\.js/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|build|\.json|\.md)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      }],
    },
    options: {
      symlinks: true,
    },
    target: 'node',
  },
];
```

The `frontend` task builds a bundle from this Javascript (ES6):

`console.log('This is the frontend calling!!');`

Simple right?

The `backend` task builds a bundle from this Javascript (ES6):

```
import Stack from 'stack-vod';

const stack = new Stack();
console.log(stack);
```

where `stack-vod` is my package that's using `ffi`.

Here's the `package.json` file for the POC app:

```
{
  "name": "stack-as-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack",
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "Zachary Abresch <zachary.abresch@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "eslint": "^3.7.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^2.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.4.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.22.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "stack-vod": "[Private Gitlab Repository]"
  }
}
```

Here are the steps to replicate the issue:

1. `npm i`
2. `npm run build`
3. `node ./wp-build/backend.bundle.js`

**Step 1** works fine. Save for a few warnings, no errors when installing `npm` packages.

**Step 2** Shows this output:

```
> stack-as-package@1.0.0 build /Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package
> webpack

Hash: 513274db1b2b97352c7b3aed8d398daba0b6527f
Version: webpack 1.13.2
Child frontend:
    Hash: 513274db1b2b97352c7b
    Version: webpack 1.13.2
    Time: 859ms
                 Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    frontend.bundle.js    1.45 kB       0  [emitted]  main
            index.html  191 bytes          [emitted]
        + 1 hidden modules
    Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
            + 3 hidden modules
Child backend:
    Hash: 3aed8d398daba0b6527f
    Version: webpack 1.13.2
    Time: 949ms
                Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    backend.bundle.js  137 kB       0  [emitted]  main
        + 40 hidden modules

    WARNING in ./~/bindings/bindings.js
    Critical dependencies:
    76:22-40 the request of a dependency is an expression
    76:43-53 the request of a dependency is an expression
     @ ./~/bindings/bindings.js 76:22-40 76:43-53

    WARNING in ./~/bindings/package.json
    Module parse failed: /Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/bindings/package.json Unexpected token (2:9)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:9)
        at Parser.pp$4.raise (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
        at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
        at Parser.pp.semicolon (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:581:61)
        at Parser.pp$1.parseExpressionStatement (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:966:10)
        at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:730:24)
        at Parser.pp$1.parseBlock (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:981:25)
        at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:709:33)
        at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
        at Parser.parse (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
        at Object.parse (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
        at Parser.parse (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
        at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
        at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
        at nextLoader (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
        at /Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
        at Storage.provide (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:52:20)
        at CachedInputFileSystem.readFile (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:140:24)
        at DependenciesBlock.onLoadPitchDone (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:255:7)
        at DependenciesBlock.loadPitch (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:182:27)
        at DependenciesBlock.doBuild (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:241:4)
        at DependenciesBlock.build (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:84:14)
        at Compilation.buildModule (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:126:9)
        at /Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:309:10
        at /Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:58:13
        at NormalModuleFactory.applyPluginsAsyncWaterfall (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:75:69)
        at onDoneResolving (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:38:11)
        at onDoneResolving (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:121:6)
        at /Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:116:7
        at /Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:726:13
        at /Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
     @ ./~/bindings ^\.\/.*$

    WARNING in ./~/bindings/README.md
    Module parse failed: /Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/bindings/README.md Unexpected token (2:3)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:3)
        at Parser.pp$4.raise (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
        at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
        at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1822:12)
        at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1715:21)
        at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1692:19)
        at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOp (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1656:43)
        at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOp (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1658:21)
        at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1639:17)
        at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1620:21)
        at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1597:21)
        at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1573:21)
        at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:727:47)
        at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
        at Parser.parse (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
        at Object.parse (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
        at Parser.parse (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
        at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
        at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
        at nextLoader (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
        at /Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
        at Storage.finished (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
        at /Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
        at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:445:3)
     @ ./~/bindings ^\.\/.*$
```

**Step 3** responds with this error:

```
/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/wp-build/backend.bundle.js:2688
    throw err
    ^

Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → /Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/build/binding.node
 → /Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/build/Debug/binding.node
 → /Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/build/Release/binding.node
 → /Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/out/Debug/binding.node
 → /Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/Debug/binding.node
 → /Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/out/Release/binding.node
 → /Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/Release/binding.node
 → /Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/build/default/binding.node
 → /Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/compiled/6.5.0/darwin/x64/binding.node
    at bindings (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/wp-build/backend.bundle.js:2685:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/wp-build/backend.bundle.js:561:52)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/wp-build/backend.bundle.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/wp-build/backend.bundle.js:466:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/wp-build/backend.bundle.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/wp-build/backend.bundle.js:80:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/wp-build/backend.bundle.js:455:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/wp-build/backend.bundle.js:20:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/wp-build/backend.bundle.js:64:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/zabresch/Documents/8x8/scratching/stack-as-package/wp-build/backend.bundle.js:20:30)
```

I've tried a *ton* of "fixes" I found on SO and GH but *none* of them have worked. Can anyone tell me what's going on here and what can be done to fix it? I've been slamming my head against this for days and 2 teammates spent days last week trying to figure this out too.

BTW, `webpack` is a requirement of my team as this will eventually be used on a larger project using `electron` and `webpack` is already being used to build there. So answers like "don't use webpack" won't cut the mustard. :)

Answer (score 1):

First things first, you may need a json and an md file loader, do `npm i -S json-loader` and `npm i -S file-loader`, and then update this in **webpack.config.js**

```
"loaders": [{
    test: /\.js/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|build)/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
 }, {
    test: /\.md(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    loader: "file"
 }, {
    test: /\.json$/,
    loader: 'json-loader'
 }]
```

If this does not resolve the issue, check if **binding.node** exists after doing this, and reply then I will update my answer.

Comment: Okay. I dropped those loaders into my `webpack.config.js` (installed as `devDependencies`). That did indeed get rid of the module parse issues but my `backend.bundle.js` still throws the same errors. After repacking with `webpack --display-error-details` I'm still seeing:

`WARNING in ./~/bindings/bindings.js
Critical dependencies:
76:22-40 the request of a dependency is an expression
76:43-53 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./~/bindings/bindings.js 76:22-40 76:43-53`

Comment: Running `node ./wp-build/backend.bundle.js` still throws `Error: Could not locate the bindings file.`

Comment: I recently encountered a similar issue, which was really a pathetic one, it was similar to what you are saying. After hours of debugging, I found out that a line in my main.js was creating this issue, I removed that and it worked fine. Sadly webpack gives errors stating something else while the actual error was something very different. You may need to check if your code is breaking at some line.

Comment: Thanks [Ammar Hasan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2071317/ammar-hasan) but my code isn't breaking (that I know of). If I build a static version using `babel`, everything works fine.